# Read string with ZSH completions

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to read a string from a user (using `read` builtin or something similar), with all completions enabled for normal shell usage. In other words, I want ZSH to complete all commands but after pressing ENTER I don't want ZSH to execute the command, but pass the string to my script. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To read a line with edition and completion, call the [`vared` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vared).

```
foo='default text'
vared foo
```

Completion will work as if you were in the value part of a parameter assignment (because that's what `vared` does). If you want completion like a normal command line, I think you need to fiddle with `_complete` to make it forget about being inside `vared`.

```
zmodload zsh/parameter
autoload +X _complete
functions[_original_complete]=$functions[_complete]
_complete () {
  unset 'compstate[vared]'
  _original_complete "$@"
}
foo='default text'
vared foo
```

Comment: Note this will fail if `_complete` has been aliased prior. You'll see output like: `defining function based on alias \`_complete'
parse error near \`()'`. Add `function` keyword before `_complete() {` function definition to fix. See this issue for more info: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/442